# Is it possible to using WebBrowser in a Thread ? (Delphi)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, browser, fill

I'm using WebBrowser control to fill a web page . is it possible to using WB inside a thread ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWebBrowser` is a VCL control. Therefore, it must be created and operated in the main VCL thread.

The control already acts asynchronously, though. When you tell it to navigate to a page, it will do that in the background and notify you (via `OnNavigateComplete` and other events) when it's finished.

Comment: Thank you . but i have another problem . the html page that i want to fill it , works with ajax techniques and often my GUI will be crashed !

Comment: That description isn't good enough to diagnose the problem. In what way does it crash? Can you reduce the situation to a minimal example of XmlHttpRequest? The answer to these questions are what you should include when you post a new Stack Overflow question about this issue.