# TWebBrowser hangs the main thread during navigating a blocking html

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

I have created a test html page which has a blocking loop. When I call `TWebBrowser.Navigate()`, the main thread hangs. But it's been said that `TWebBrowser` works asynchronously. It doesn't look so!

Here is a simple html file

```
<html>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    function writeIt() {
        i++;
        var start = Date.now();
        var element = document.getElementById("test");
        if (element) {
            while (Date.now() < start + 15000) {
                element.innerHTML = i;
                i++;
            } 
        }
    }
    function startIt() {
        writeIt();
        //setTimeout(writeIt, 1000);        
    }
    //window.onload=startIt();
</script>
<body>

    <div id="test"></div>
    <script>
        startIt();      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Project to demonstrate:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Button1: TButton;
    FileOpenDialog1: TFileOpenDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FileOpenDialog1.Execute then
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(FileOpenDialog1.FileName);
end;

end.
```

After calling `WebBrowser1.Navigate()` on this html file, the main thread hangs for 15 seconds.

Are there any solutions to prevent `TWebBrowser` from blocking the main thread?

UPDATE:
It seems that Javascript starts locking the thread right after the `BeforeScriptExecute` event is fired. If I use `Application.ProcessMessages()` here, Javascript never executes. I'm still trying to find a solution to fix this.

Comment: There is nothing you can do, this is not a Delphi issue but an IE issue (TWebbrowser is a thin wrapper for IE's activeX browser control). Try your file in internet explorer, you will see that IE does not respond... The only solution is to use a Chromium/dcef solution...

Comment: cef3 is buggy and full of AVs. Also when you click, it opens in the main window. Even if i handle it in BeforeNavigate it doesn't run correctly

Comment: I used Chromium with success in quite a number of projects, but anyway, If want to stick with TWebbrowser and Internet Exploder, you will have to move TWebbrowser into another process to avoid blocking of your main message pump. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17672459/800214) might help.

Comment: @Khun, I am not sure about Delphi specifically, but in C#, VB.net, C++, and F#, the web browser control has always behaved this way.  Navigate is a blocking call on whatever thread the web browser control is loaded onto. So, your bet is to put it on a separate thread. If you can't do that because its on the GUI thread, you can have 2 of them and set the document of the one on the GUI thread to the html that loaded as a result of navigating the other one.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett but there is no way you can use TWebBrowser in a separate thread

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can do, this is not a Delphi issue but an IE issue (`TWebbrowser` is a thin wrapper for IE's ActiveX browser control). 
The call to Navigate will block until the javascript has been executed.
Test your file in Internet Explorer, and you will see that IE does not respond.
The only way out is to use a Chromium/DCEF based solution or to [move the TWebbrowser in its own process/thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17672459/800214).

Comment: Sorry but this is not a solution. dcef3 is buggy and full of AVs. You also need to deploy lots of files (like 75mb ?)

Comment: sorry to pop your bubble, but it is what it is. I have used dcef in many projects and I don't have AV's as you mentioned but indeed you will need to distribute some DLL's.

Comment: DLLs? Do you mean putting TWebBrowser in a DLL?

Comment: Yes, or in another EXE (see linked answer)

Comment: @Khun::Sorry but this is not a solution." Maybe not one you like, but it answers the q you asked, esp the link to the article about TWebBrowser in its own process/thread.  Btw, if you look in the Threads view inder Debug Windows in the Delphi IDE, you will see that TWebBrowser has several threads associated with it.

Comment: And again "This is not a solution". I already know there is no easy way to fix it. But this is not a solution. I am not trying to be rude. I am just telling my toughts.

Comment: @Khun: denial is the first step towards resolution. Hate Microsoft, not me :)

Comment: @Khun: it must run in it's own thread. You can also do this with an out of process COM server (ActiveX DLL like told in linked answer) or another process (EXE)

Comment: As far as I remember, I once tried to create a separate child process to hold `TWebBrowser`, but once I set the child window parent handle to the main process window  I was back to nothing. the main process was hang again while the WB was loading synchronous JS. maybe I'm mistaken as it was a long time ago - OP should check it. I haven't tried the out of process ActiveX approach though... There is actually a big chance that this has NO solution at all, if the same behavior happens in an IE browser.

Comment: @kobik well i have tried child process way and same happened to me. It still hangs the main thread. I haven't tried ActiveX way either. I'm looking for ways to do that anyway. But you are right! Running new process is not a solution either. And again maybe you are right! Maybe there are no solutions.

Comment: Well you can try the ActiveX. If that works you have a solution. It was mentioned to work in the linked answer.

Comment: Also I am not sure that dcef will behave any different with the code in the queation... Imo it will block the main ui. Not tested.

Comment: @Kobik: I tested the page in Chrome and it does not block, don't know if it applies to chromium though.

Comment: I have tested in Chromium and It doesn't block in chromium